# Problems with dojo event and Jquery

Tags: jquery

I can't find the answer in the other posts.

I use:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js
and
libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js

I need to read the event of the client of my dijit.form.ComboBox.

I have used all, .live , .click but i obtain the same results; nothing.

```
         $('#Place').live('change',(function () {    

            alert("Campos ocultos OK"); 
          }));
```

or

```
        $('#Place').click (function ()
        {
            var thischeck = $(this);
            alert("Ok1");
            if (thischeck.is (':checked'))
               {
                  alert("OK2");
               }
        });
```

Could somebody help me please?

Where i'm worng?

Thank you very much,

Álvaro

Comment: can you please post your markup? In that case the generated markup i guess.. Have you already tried to inspect those elements with firebug or the chrome dev tools (or something like that)?

Comment: Another very good tool to find events is http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2